# SSL hostname verification in tyrus standalone client

Tags: java, ssl, tyrus

I'm using tyrus 1.7 standalone client to connect to a remote websocket.
This is done like in the sample: https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.7/user-guide.html#websocket-client-endpoint

In the default implementation only  checks if the SSL certificate chain is valid but it doesn't care if the hostname is wrong. This seems to be a big security risk.

When testing the raw HTTPS connecton to the websocket server (without websocket upgrade) via [HttpsURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) the hostname and chain verification works as expected.

Is there a way of activation SSL hostname verification in the tyrus standalone client?

Comment: Can you please file this as an issue against Tyrus - https://java.net/jira/browse/TYRUS ?

Comment: filed as TYRUS-339: https://java.net/jira/browse/TYRUS-339

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works out of the box with the latest version from the repository.

The features was added in following commit:
https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/commit/5ca23a3493b0730a5881a78e9fd8bdab95d31705